# I dont know how to divide using array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, division

the code

```
int a;
Double sum = 0.0;

System.out.print("Length of num you want to add: ");
a = in.nextInt();
num = new double [a];

for(int i = 0;i<num.length;i++)
{
System.out.print("Num["+(i+1)+"]:" );
num[i] = in.nextDouble();
sum += num[i];
System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
```

}
instead of addition i want the code to be division

Comment: Division of what by what?

Comment: instead of adding numbers while its looping. Its dividing numbers

Comment: be cautious of division as you need to check for zero before writing `sum = sum/ num[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the addition to division then all you have to do is change the line

```
sum += num[i];
```

to

```
sum /= num[i];
```

This will divide sum by num[i] instead of adding num[i] to it.

Comment: As long as "sum" is not initialized as zero.

Comment: no that is okay. I tried to divide with zero and it ended up with zero.

Comment: 0 divided by anything will always return 0 so it's still a safe method.

Comment: i want the first number to be divided to the next number tho.@Edd

Comment: be cautious about num[i] being 0 at runtime. u need to check it before performing the division